# JavaScript is not doing what I ask it to! Why is that?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to check a variable to see if it contains 'http://' and if it doesnt, to append http to it.  Using the code below but all I get is the page refreshing with `/?myURL=` being appended to the browsers address bar.
Removing the `if(getUrl.indexOF("http://" == -1)` part will make the code work correctly, but will then lack the functionality it contains.
I cant figure out where I am going wrong.  Am I missing a break or return in the if else statement?

```
function placeUrl()
    {
    var str1 = "http://"
    var getUrl;
    var newUrl;

    getUrl = document.getElementById('usersUrl').value;

    if(getUrl != null)
        {
        if(getUrl.indexOf("http://" == -1)
            {
            newUrl = str1.concat(getUrl);
            }
        else
            {
            newUrl = getUrl;
            }

        document.getElementById('iframe1').src = newUrl;
        }

    return false;
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<form onSubmit="return placeUrl()">
    <input id="usersUrl" type="text" name="myURL" value="Enter a URL..." onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter a URL...';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter a URL...') {this.value = '';}">
    <input type="submit" value="Analyse">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give this a less generic title?

Comment: if(getUrl.indexOf("http://" == -1)
 Needs one more bracket!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem you have is that you miss a brace. Change the line to:

```
if(getUrl.indexOf("http://"/*HERE*/)/*HERE*/ == -1)
```

I have added comments to indicate which is the missing bracket.

Comment: Oh my god how did I miss that!

Comment: I always seem to make mistakes like this.  A lot of times I will be writing code for a long period of time I will miss error like this when I check it over.  The best thing is to take a short break, get a drink or snack, and come back to it.